# How to pass event to named function on.('click')?

Tags: jquery

I have the following trigger in jquery:

```
$('.text').on('click', '.readless', contract);
```

In contract, I want to use `event.preventDefault()` but this doesn't work in firefox, so I need to pass the event to contract. How do I do this?

Comment: Just accept `event` as first argument? `function contract(event) { ... }`

Comment: See the example in the jQuery `preventDefault()` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/#example-0

Comment: another example http://jsfiddle.net/DVPrk/

Comment: I'd love an explanation for the downvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(function () {

    // Attach Event
    // new way (jQuery 1.7+) - on(events, selector, handler);
    $('.text').on('click', '.readless', contract);

    function contract(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(e.type);
    }

    // Create elements dynamically
    $('.text').append('<div class="readless">click me</div>');
});
```

After adding a reference of the function `contract` to the `on()` method, the `event` or `e` variable is automatically passed to the function as the first argument.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zPvKf/)

Answer (score 3):

Are you 'passing' e on the contract function?

```
contract(e){
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

even without passing it from the click event, the e var should be available on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

This is how an inline function would look like.  I'd also use `stopPropagation`.

```
$('.text').on('click', '.readless', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems like you don't need to *pass* the argument, but you just need to set it up so the function *receives* it.  Taking a quick peak at the [api.query.com documentation](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) for `bind()`...

> `$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function( event ) {`

So, all you should need to do is `$("#foo").bind("click", functionName)` and define function as `function(event) {...}`.  In your specific case...

```
function contract(e) {
    return e.preventDefault();
}
```

[**Simple, working demo**](https://jsbin.com/guyoqot/3/edit?html,js,output).